# How to use expansion panel component inside md-card in angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-ui, angular-material2

I have angular 2 application where, I am displaying tiles using md-card.I want to add an expansion panel inside md-card. On click of the panel, it should expand and display some content. Is it possible to add such a component inside md-card? Or is there any better way of designing it? Like display some expandable tiles/cards ? I checked these links online, it shows a list which can be expanded. I am not sure if I can use this inside card. https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-expansion-panels
https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#expansion-panels-behavior

> these are the versions used   "@angular/core": "2.4.10"
>   "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2"

below is the sample md-card usage

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap  style="padding-bottom: 15px; 
padding-top: 15px; margin:auto; justify-content: center;background-color:paleturquoise;" >  
  <md-card fxFlex.gt-md="30" fxFlex.md="30"  fxFlex.sm="auto" fxFlex.xs="100" *ngFor="let data of myData" style="margin:10px;">
  <md-card-content >  
    <h1>Name: {{data.name}} </h1> 
  <h3 [ngStyle]="{'margin-top': '-3px','margin-bottom': '20px'}">{{data.time | date:'HH:mm:ss, MMMM dd'}}</h3>
  <h2>content1: {{data.somedata1 }}</h2>
  <h2>content2: {{data.somedata2}}</h2>
  <h2>content3: {{data.somedata2}}</h2>
  <h2>content4: {{data.somedata3}}</h2>
  <h3>
    <a routerLink="">some link here</a> 
    </h3>
    // Add expansion panel or collapsable UI component here
  </md-card-content>
  </md-card> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to use ng2-expansion-panels for Angular 2 application. https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-expansion-panels

sample code

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap  style="padding-bottom: 15px; 
    padding-top: 15px; margin:auto; justify-content: center;background-color:paleturquoise;" >  
    <md-card fxFlex.gt-md="30" fxFlex.md="30"  fxFlex.sm="auto" fxFlex.xs="100" *ngFor="let data of myData" style="margin:10px;"
[ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': data.time > timeLimit1  ? '#69F0AE':(data.time < timeLimit2  ? '#FF5252':'yellow' )}">
        <md-card-content >  
        <h1>Name: {{data.name}} </h1> 
        <h3 [ngStyle]="{'margin-top': '-3px','margin-bottom': '20px'}">{{data.time | date:'HH:mm:ss, MMMM dd'}}</h3>
        <h3>
        <a routerLink="">some link here</a> 
        </h3>
            <expansion-panels-container>
                <expansion-panel >
                <expansion-panel-title>
                Title1
                </expansion-panel-title>
                <expansion-panel-content>
                <h2>content1: {{data.somedata1 }}</h2>
                <h2>content2: {{data.somedata2}}</h2>
                <h2>content3: {{data.somedata2}}</h2>
                <h2>content4: {{data.somedata3}}</h2>
                </expansion-panel-content>
                </expansion-panel>
                <expansion-panel>
                <expansion-panel-title>
                Title2
                </expansion-panel-title>
                <expansion-panel-content>
                <h2>content2: {{data.somedata2}}</h2>
                <h2>content3: {{data.somedata2}}</h2>
                <h2>content4: {{data.somedata3}}</h2>
                </expansion-panel-content>
                </expansion-panel>
            </expansion-panels-container>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card> 
    </div>
```